# How can I fix my simple Haskell CLI program to show the contents of a file?

Tags: haskell

So I'm going through the examples in the [CmdArgs documentation](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/darcs/cmdargs/cmdargs.htm), and I'm trying to build off the Hello World program in order to make a simple CLI program that takes a filename as input, and just shows the contents of that file (like `cat`). But I'm a Haskell beginner, and have virtually no idea what I'm doing. Here's what I have so far:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
module ShowFile where
import System.Console.CmdArgs

data ShowFile = ShowFile {file :: Maybe FilePath}
              deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)

showFile = ShowFile
  {file = def &= typ "FILE" &= argPos 0}

main = print =<< cmdArgs showFile
```

And so running `runhaskell mycat.hs test.txt` shows:

```
ShowFile {file = Just "test.txt"}
```

So something's working! Now how do I get it to display the contents of `test.txt` instead? I've been trying things like:

```
main = getContents showFile
```

but haven't stumbled on the right thing yet.

Comment: Can you write a function of type `ShowFile -> IO ()` which does what you want? Replace `print` with that function.

Comment: if you run into (run-time) problems with cmdargs - try "optparse applicative", I had a few problems with it quite recently, and switched over to that. But it might be a bit more difficult to work with that as a beginner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pattern match on the option.

```
main = do
    options <- cmdArgs showFile
    contents <- case options of
        ShowFile { file = Nothing } -> getContents
        ShowFile { file = Just f  } -> readFile f
    putStr contents
```